# Python socket server: listening to multiple clients

Tags: python, sockets

I must listen to incoming connections but at the same time I have to receive the messages from the already connected clients. However `listen(1)` makes the socket waiting so I can't receive them. What to do? (I have to get the messages as soon as the client sends them)

Comment: your question is not specific enough. what socket type are you using? Look at some UDP or TCP socket tutorials to find out what you want to know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in short, you have 3 main options:

1. open a thread per client, that spawns after you `accept()`, and the run a loop in this context, that does `read() => .... => write()`
2. run a main loop that uses `select()` on clients after `accept()` for each, and handle dispatching yourself.
3. best option - use an async networking framework like `tornado`, `gevent`, `twisted` or a few more to handle this transparently.